# Xcode 7.x crashes when editing storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, interface-builder

Xcode is crashing very often when I edit storyboards.

I'm working with **OS X El Capitan 10.11** and **Xcode 7.0.1** (7A1001).

I've experienced crashes mostly when I edit view background colors and view alphas.

The only way to keep going for the moment has been saving after every edition.

It's really annoying though. Have you experience these crashes? Do you know any workaround? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It also crashes often when editing constraints.

Here's the crash log:

```
Process:               Xcode [10557]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.0.1 (8228)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8228000000000000~5
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       813434267
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [10557]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-14 12:38:50.754 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        AE86FBDD-3DF0-170B-2EDC-C5C7B67C46E0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A5845897-DD62-4799-B12E-DF0EB270E578

Time Awake Since Boot: 95000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       90000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        36  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000012639b000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x12639b000:
    CG backing stores      0000000126387000-000000012639b000 [   80K] rw-/rw- SM=PRV  
--> 
    CoreAnimation          000000012639c000-00000001263cb000 [  188K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A1001
```

**EDIT 2**

I was hoping that new updates would fix this issue but **Xcode 7.1 (7B91b) is still crashing** when editing constraints in storyboards, using OS X El Capitan 10.11.1

Comment: Hey there. Did you try cleaning Xcode? perhaps there is a problem with the cache cause i have no issues at all

Comment: reset your simulator issue will be resolved.

Comment: Hi @Korpel, thanks for your response, how do I clean Xcode?

Comment: Quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually
clean and reset Xcode
reset Simulator
restart Xcode
or eventually restart your macbook
Cleaning is under product if i remember correct

Comment: Glad i could help you gonna put it as an answer for other people they might have the problem to be able to solve it:) have a good day

Comment: Same issue. Tried going back to 7.0, and also tried the 7.1 beta but still crashes. I can't remember whether it was happening on 7.0 or whether it start on 7.0.1. Did you find any fix for this?

Comment: Hi @myles, it's good to know I'm not alone with this issue. I didn't find any way to fix it yet.

Comment: It's really hard to work with Xcode crashing all the time when editing autolayout constraints in storyboards....anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you filed a radar? You should file a radar: http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: I've just raised a bug report to http://bugreporter.apple.com with id 23496025 and title "Xcode crashes editing storyboards" @RobertAtkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Xcode 7.1.1 (7B1005) fixes this issue:

[image]

I have updated to this version.

I'm also using default screen resolution in my mac.

Xcode is not crashing anymore when editing storyboards.

Comment: This seems to have fixed a lot of the issues for me, but it is still crashing sometimes when I change colours of things such as `UILabel` using interface builder. Does this happen for you?

Comment: No crashes since 7.1.1 @myles I have not changed colours of labels yet though

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting a lot of crashes for things like changing colours, constraints, positions etc. Have you still not had any since the update?

Comment: The truth is I haven't used a lot Xcode since 7.1.1 update @myles. But I tried some operations that crashed 100% with 7.1 and everything worked fine.

Comment: Yeah that's how it started it with me too. Seemed to work fine for all things that had previously caused issues for about 30-40 mins... and then the crashes started again and have slowly increased in frequency.

Comment: I'm using build 7B1005 but still get constant crashing.  I'm using IBInspectables, but I'm not sure if thats part of the issue.  I issued another bug (23574802) to Apple.

Comment: I'm still having this issue too, but I have another project that doesn't have them. Main difference between the two is that the new project is just a few months old, the crashing project is a few years old now (started shortly after the release of Swift) and has been upgraded across several versions of Xcode. It's like some piece of cruft in the Storyboard is pissing off Xcode.

Comment: It still crashes I have tried all the possible tricks mentioned but no use.Its very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

Like I told you in the comments a cleaning of Xcode and the simulator might solve the issue.
This is what i followed in the past:

- Quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually
- clean and reset Xcode
- reset Simulator
- restart Xcode
- eventually restart your macbook

You can also do this but there may be some loss. Some times it helps though:

- delete ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

edit:
Changing the resolution of your retina to "more space" will most likely fix your issue and you will get no more storyboard crashes. Thanks @Julian Ko!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that Xcode keeps crashing when I edit constraints. I've added the crash log for more details.

Comment: damn that sucks. Ok we'll figure it out

Comment: By clean out do you mean delete all the contents?

Comment: @Subash  try this out to completely remove some of the cache of Xcode : rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"

Answer (score 2):

It proves that Apple is now the big brother we all come to hate... Head of OS engineering and QA should be let go!. EVERY single release there are problems like this one.

This is still present in xcode 7.2 & 10.11.2:

```
Process:               Xcode [1357]
Path:                  /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.2 (9548)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9548000000000000~7
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       814662604
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1357]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-01-03 12:59:48.024 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A204h)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4B468882-21F6-7737-2427-6DA26AD19FD7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DBD77D2F-DAC4-4519-960F-3D09A1F20100

Time Awake Since Boot: 5700 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7fe89e5dd840> from <NSButton: 0x7fe89e5df770>
ProductBuildVersion: 7C68
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSOpenPanel setAccessoryViewDisclosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe89e5f5290
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7fe89e5dd840> from <NSButton: 0x7fe89e5df770>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff94e04ef4 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010cbbdc67 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff98a208e8 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff94e07fcd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff94d428a1 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff94d42428 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x000000010e119038 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant setupSavePanel:] (in IDEKit)
  7  0x000000010e1191c4 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant configuredOpenPanel] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x000000011c0fe982 -[Xcode3ProjectTemplateCompletionAssistant configuredSavePanel] (in Xcode3UI)
  9  0x000000010e1193f6 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant beginSheetModalForWindow:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x000000010e1199d4 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant finishWithCompletionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 11  0x000000010df569c6 -[IDEAssistantWindowController goNextOrFinish:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x00007fff950577a1 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff92ff5508 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 14  0x000000010d19dac7 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 15  0x000000010cbbd9a5 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 16  0x000000010d06f1f7 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 17  0x00007fff9300a52e -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
 18  0x00007fff9300a458 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 19  0x00007fff950577a1 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 20  0x00007fff9300a3b5 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 21  0x00007fff950577a1 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 22  0x00007fff930089de -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 23  0x00007fff9305d26e -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff93007116 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff935a103b -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff935a22ff -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff92f0db9a -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff92f0a32d -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x000000010de0ec6d -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 30  0x00007fff92e3a734 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff92dbcc4f NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff8fec75ad start (in libdyld.dylib)

Reset Traditional Character Shape
Performing @selector(goNextOrFinish:) from sender NSButton 0x7fe89e5df770
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94e04f0c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010cbbdc67 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 194
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff98a208e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94e07fcd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d428a1 ___forwarding___ + 1009
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d42428 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
6   IDEKit                              0x000000010e119038 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant setupSavePanel:] + 871
7   IDEKit                              0x000000010e1191c4 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant configuredOpenPanel] + 64
8   Xcode3UI                            0x000000011c0fe982 -[Xcode3ProjectTemplateCompletionAssistant configuredSavePanel] + 37
9   IDEKit                              0x000000010e1193f6 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant beginSheetModalForWindow:] + 81
10  IDEKit                              0x000000010e1199d4 -[IDETemplateCompletionAssistant finishWithCompletionBlock:] + 644
11  IDEKit                              0x000000010df569c6 -[IDEAssistantWindowController goNextOrFinish:] + 651
12  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff950577a1 _os_activity_initiate + 75
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff92ff5508 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
14  DVTKit                              0x000000010d19dac7 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 379
15  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010cbbd9a5 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint + 83
16  DVTKit                              0x000000010d06f1f7 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 335
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff9300a52e -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff9300a458 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
19  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff950577a1 _os_activity_initiate + 75
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff9300a3b5 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
21  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff950577a1 _os_activity_initiate + 75
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff930089de -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2693
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9305d26e -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 744
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff93007116 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 657
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff935a103b -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6039
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff935a22ff -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 150
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff92f0db9a -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 494
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff92f0a32d -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2561
29  IDEKit                              0x000000010de0ec6d -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 739
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff92e3a734 -[NSApplication run] + 796
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff92dbcc4f NSApplicationMain + 1176
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8fec75ad start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e096 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1fb5cd pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92bf483b abort + 129
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e031df1 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1481
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e03308a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 1077
5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e033156 IDEHandleUncaughtException + 94
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92e3a7d8 -[NSApplication run] + 960
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92dbcc4f NSApplicationMain + 1176
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8fec75ad start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617f08a kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efee7f1 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 251
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efee445 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff961789c6 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96177e07 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d08504 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d079cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d07218 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff905dca51 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000115ba55e0 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 1103
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90727866 __NSThread__start__ + 1331
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e20a __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d5405a __CFSocketManager + 762
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff961789c6 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96177e07 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d08504 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d079cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d07218 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8baf11d2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90727866 __NSThread__start__ + 1331
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff961789c6 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96177e07 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d08504 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d079cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d07218 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92f06535 _NSEventThread + 149
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff961789c6 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96177e07 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d08504 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d079cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d07218 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff905dca51 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9064e444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011ffc9071 -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90727866 __NSThread__start__ + 1331
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e772 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f97d9 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: TBrowserViewDataSource
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617df46 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1fa1c8 _pthread_cond_wait + 711
2   com.apple.FinderKit             0x00007fff8f41b05c ModifyDataSourceOnMainThreadSync(FI_TBrowserViewDataSource*, FI_TBVDSChangedNotificationData*, std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 442
3   com.apple.FinderKit             0x00007fff8f41c18e __48-[FI_TBrowserViewDataSource openContainerNodes:]_block_invoke + 3695
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efed814 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efe9765 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efed1a6 _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efecd63 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 200
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efec567 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 530
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8efec353 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f973f _pthread_wqthread + 1129
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e772 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f97d9 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e772 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f97d9 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e772 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f97d9 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e772 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f97d9 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e772 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f97d9 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6d95 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff961789c6 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96177e07 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d08504 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d079cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94d07218 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff94dc7261 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8a20269a SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 346
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9617e29a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92c15b15 nanosleep + 199
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff87afd6ff 0x7fff87aeb000 + 75519
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9cc3 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f9c40 _pthread_start + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a1f6da5 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff532809c8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000160b  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff532809f0  rsp: 0x00007fff532809c8
   r8: 0x00007fe89b300f32   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff98a17270  r13: 0x00007fe89f88d230  r14: 0x00007fff779a4368  r15: 0x00007fe899503100
  rip: 0x00007fff9617e096  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff78eb3008

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10c97f000 -        0x10c982fff  com.apple.dt.Xcode (7.2 - 9548) <278C9A25-1A00-3F35-990F-7D9C31D6E68C> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x10c98e000 -        0x10ce6aff7  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (7.2 - 9542) <B724084D-17E4-3239-A5CF-5B180BB42009> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x10d063000 -        0x10d3abff7  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (7.2 - 9542) <3F5B58D5-F5C3-3E1A-A78C-743626E5EA36> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x10d5bb000 -        0x10dab1ff7  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (7.2 - 9548) <4828AF1E-2AB7-35B9-A673-A046F8C5CE00> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x10ddf5000 -        0x10e685fff  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (7.2 - 9548) <CAC455DE-07E1-34C8-93D7-A44B9D0E55A0> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x10ec81000 -        0x10ecb0fcf  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices (1.0 - 59500) <80184D81-3338-3F51-B762-CAD4BACCE6CA> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/Versions/A/DTXConnectionServices
       0x10ecde000 -        0x10ed65fff  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsFoundation (1.0 - 59500) <8B4DAB4C-807A-3B99-9E64-D0CE025B8594> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTInstrumentsFoundation
       0x10eddb000 -        0x10ee1dfff  com.apple.framework.ConfigurationProfiles (8.0 - 827) <09DD26D2-C022-30DF-960E-6D8D1BC956C4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConfigurationProfiles.framework/Versions/A/ConfigurationProfiles
       0x10ee44000 -        0x10eecbfff  com.apple.CoreSymbolicationDT (3.1 - 59500) <D8BE8839-E140-335F-843E-41FFD4D681C7> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolicationDT
       0x10eee1000 -        0x10ef2ffd7  com.apple.Symbolication (1.4 - 59004) <683F855A-47CB-3AC5-9DCA-77AF36712A27> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SymbolicationDT.framework/Versions/A/SymbolicationDT
       0x10ef66000 -        0x10ef67fff  libpanel.5.4.dylib (46) <CE760336-1492-3D17-9B6E-BA99F91DEE71> /usr/lib/libpanel.5.4.dylib
       0x10ef6c000 -        0x10ef85ff7  com.apple.network.statistics.framework (1.2 - 1) <C747290E-FAE2-3308-9DFA-68337E7FD914> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/Versions/A/NetworkStatistics
       0x10efa1000 -        0x10f0d9fff  com.apple.framework.CoreProfileDT (59003) <EBC583AF-1F52-3337-B140-43777DDA209D> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreProfileDT.framework/Versions/A/CoreProfileDT
       0x10f118000 -        0x10f11cff7  com.apple.kperf (1.0 - 1) <0903A717-AD17-30A5-8171-57F3A972631E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/kperf.framework/Versions/A/kperf
       0x10f125000 -        0x10f125fff  com.apple.Metal (1.0 - 1) <00700144-FA34-38BA-A8F4-55C8B7A9D348> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Metal.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/Metal
       0x10f12b000 -        0x10f135ff7  com.apple.kperfdataDT (1.0 - 1) <6007D8DE-C6A5-3F06-99F8-4F5AFEB98740> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/kperfdataDT.framework/Versions/A/kperfdataDT
       0x10f13d000 -        0x10f13dff7  com.apple.xcode.compilers.coredata (9.2 - 9523) <04476688-4DF3-3AB4-8E57-06BE754B1EBB> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue. Every time I try to edit my storyboard, Xcode decides that it is not willing to operate anymore. I also got the new version of Xcode, namely 7.1.1 (7B1005)

After some trying and experiencing a lot of crashes, I managed to find a workaround. I don't know if it applies to you, but I was using two screens in developing iOS apps. I disconnected one (the non-retina of course)and never experienced this issue again. Right after it I could code, even no restart needed from xCode.

Weird, but since I have little time, the only way to go now.

Comment: Interesting...I'm using an external monitor too. Thanks for your workaround!

Comment: Same here, will have to give this a test.

Comment: Same here and disconnecting from external display worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me all the time when I try to modify something in storyboard. I could conclude what is the actions I did to cause the issue. Then I change the resolution on my retina Macbook Pro from default to more space. It never comes again. I guess it changed some behaviours drawing to the screen. You might want to try it.

Comment: I've tried to change my resolution in my Macbook Pro Retina 15" from default to more space. Surprisingly, since I did that I haven't experience any crash editing my storyboards. Thanks you so much for this info, it really helped. The only problem with this solution is that you could end blind with this screen resolution in your mac. It's a good workaround though if you use an external monitor. I hope  Apple will fix this issue soon or there's a better solution until that happens.

Comment: Just setting to the one between default and more space also works and is not too difficult to read. Hope the previous bug opened to Apple brought some focus on this issue to them.

Comment: Think this works for me as well but its a horrible workaround that burns me eyes haha. Hopefully someone might find a different fix.

Comment: @JulianKo see my answer to this issue: Xcode 7.1.1 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed for me after updating:

- **Xcode** to version **7.2**
- **El Capitan** to version **10.11.2**

Comment: yep... still crashing and now it's 7.3 (to infinity and beyond!):

Answer (score 0):

The crash still exist in the latest Xcode (7.3.1).

When you select storyboard from Project Navigator, **let it finish building**. Thats all.

Once it finish building, you can go to another storyboard without any crash.