# Xcode crash after adding run script

Tags: xcode, xcode7, crashlytics

So, here is a problem with `crashlytics` run script the Xcode 7.x crashes when I  add the run script and wants to go any other tab or file.

**But there is no problem when I run it on the Xcode 8.x**

Comment: Please go through below link. it will help you. [Xcode 7x crashes problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107995/xcode-7-x-crashes-when-editing-storyboards)